# get nested item from request.json python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a piece of code like below

```
url = "https://blockchain.info/balance?active="+pub
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

above code prints below output

```
{u'0jhke23k23k4j4k3434kk54l54': {u'final_balance': 0, u'n_tx': 0, u'total_received': 0}}
```

all I want is the `final_balance` and `total_received`

I tried below code

```
print("{} {:20} {:20}".format(pub, r.json()['final_balance'], r.json()['total_received']']))
```

but it gives me this error

```
KeyError: 'final_balance'
```

so how to get only `final_balance` from this output --> `{u'0jhke23k23k4j4k3434kk54l54': {u'final_balance': 0, u'n_tx': 0, u'total_received': 0}}`

??

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that it if you received and parsed the JSON successfully, then *how* you got it does not matter to the *problem*, and therefore the *question*. Please read [mre]. In fact, it is not actually a question about JSON, but about *dictionaries*. (Also, please strongly consider upgrading your Python. It's free, and 2.7 has not been supported for more than two years. It is equivalent to using Windows 7 as your operating system, in terms of outdatedness.)

Comment: "but it gives me this error" Well, yes; that isn't a key in the dictionary. There is one key in that dictionary: `u'0jhke23k23k4j4k3434kk54l54'`. Its value is *another* dictionary, which has the key you want. So you have to do the "look up in dictionary by key" logic twice.